# How to calculate the distance between two latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geocoding, haversine

I'm trying to calculate the distance between Vancouver and Toronto using their latitude and longitudes. I'm using **haversine** formula. I'm expecting a distance of around 4390 km. Can someone tell me what mistake I'm making. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title></title>
</head>
<body onload="getDistance()">
<script>
    // Convert Degress to Radians
    function Deg2Rad( deg ) {
       return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    function getDistance()
    {       
        //Toronto Latitude  43.74 and longitude  -79.37
        //Vancouver Latitude  49.25 and longitude  -123.12
        lat1 = Deg2Rad(43.74); 
        lat2 = Deg2Rad(49.25); 
        lon1 = Deg2Rad(-79.37); 
        lon2 = Deg2Rad(-123.12);
        latDiff = lat2-lat1;
        lonDiff = lon2-lon1;
        var R = 6371000; // metres
        var φ1 = lat1;
        var φ2 = lat2;
        var Δφ = Deg2Rad(latDiff);
        var Δλ = Deg2Rad(lonDiff);

        var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
                Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
                Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

        var d = R * c;
        alert('d: ' + d);

        var dist = Math.acos( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) + Math.cos(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2) * Math.cos(Δλ) ) * R;
        alert('dist: ' + dist);
    }       
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I run this code, I get quite different numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Comment: Result of the above code doesn't produce correct numbers and I need some help. I know Haversine question has been asked here before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should expect more like 3358km. http://www.distancefromto.net/distance-from/Toronto/to/Vancouver

Here is a fiddle with the correct result: https://jsfiddle.net/Lk1du2L1/

And in that case, you'll be correct if you'd remove your deg2rad form your secondary results - you're doing it too often:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title></title>
</head>
<body onload="getDistance()">
<script>
    // Convert Degress to Radians
    function Deg2Rad( deg ) {
       return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    function getDistance()
    {       
        //Toronto Latitude  43.74 and longitude  -79.37
        //Vancouver Latitude  49.25 and longitude  -123.12
        lat1 = Deg2Rad(43.74); 
        lat2 = Deg2Rad(49.25); 
        lon1 = Deg2Rad(-79.37); 
        lon2 = Deg2Rad(-123.12);
        latDiff = lat2-lat1;
        lonDiff = lon2-lon1;
        var R = 6371000; // metres
        var φ1 = lat1;
        var φ2 = lat2;
        var Δφ = latDiff;
        var Δλ = lonDiff;

        var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
                Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
                Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

        var d = R * c;
        alert('d: ' + d);

        var dist = Math.acos( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) + Math.cos(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2) * Math.cos(Δλ) ) * R;
        alert('dist: ' + dist);
    }       
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I know, I can't find the mistake I'm making in the code. When I run the code, I get quite a different number 85568.6616.

Comment: look at the code I posted. When I run you code with those changes,  I get the correct distance: `d: 3355945.3482`

Comment: You already converted deg2rad when you created your lat1 & lat2 etc variables. When you do it again, you are changing your values and getting the incorrect `85568.661` number.

Comment: I changed my code. Removed the duplicate and now I get dist: 615456.6054867743 which doesn't look correct either.

Comment: I reposted the whole code. When I run this, I get `3355945.3482`

Comment: when i added this code in my angularjs project i am getting illegal character error while compiling.

Comment: maybe it is having trouble with those greek characters?

Comment: Yes greek characters are making trouble. when i replace it with the normal character it is working.